# Duplicate QR code for authenticator app

Tags: android

Is it possible to duplicate the qr code for an authenticator app in such a way that you could have an account with the same code on two separate devices.

Answer (score 1):

The QR code you're supposed to scan when setting up your authenticator app contains a secret key (the seed) as well as the hashing algorithm and the number of digits. Nothing prevents you from scanning this code on multiple devices or taking a photo of it to enroll future devices later.

Comment: Not even if during initial enrolement it was used as an OTP somehow?